# What permission do i need for my calculator app?

Tags: android

I have developed a basic calculator application, it does not access internet and just performs basic calculations. What permission does it still need from user and where should i define those permissions.

Answer (score 2):

If it's just a simple calculator where you input the calculation and it just displays a result, it shouldn't require any special permissions.

If an app requires permissions, they get declared in AndroidManifest.xml.  The basic information is outlined at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#permissions if you ever need it for future reference (or you're just curious).

Answer (score 0):

All Permissions are defined in AndroidManifest.xml

like this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PERMISSION" />
```

Depends on what your app wants to do though. You can find a list of android permissions here.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html